# Declaring non user code as user code when Just My Code is enabled

Tags: c#, .net

I want to break before (on a break point) an exception is thrown in code that is not mine (a WSDL generated proxy class) but still have just my code enabled everywhere else. Is there an attribute or some other way to do this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Visual Studio. Go to Debug->Exceptions dialog and check the exceptions you want the debugger to break at.

Comment: Sorry, I phrased the question incorrectly. I would like to break on a breakpoint before the exception.

Comment: Do as @DanBrum said. The debugger will stop immediately when the exception happens. Now put a breakpoint as needed.

Comment: @DanBrum, if you do as I said, the debugger will break at the exception. then you can look at the call stack and place a breakpoint higher up the call stack where you want. Then re-start your project.

Comment: I want the breakpoint in the code that is not mine. You cannot do this unless just my code is disabled. The breakpoint will not be hit. And I want the breakpoint to be hit before the exception is fired.